# Bijective linear transformation and continuous inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, continuity, solution-verification

Let $T: E \rightarrow F$ be a bijective linear transformation, where $(E,\|\cdot\|_1)$ and $(F,\| \cdot \|_2)$ are normed spaces. Show that $T^-1$ is continuous if, and only if, exists $\alpha>0$ satisfying $$\|T(x)\|_2 \geq \alpha \|x\|_1 \ \forall  \ x \in E.$$

My attempt:

Let $\|T(x)\|_2 \geq \alpha \|x\|_1$ and suppose that $T^{-1}$ is not continuous, then $T^{-1}$ is not bounded and we have $$\|T^{-1}(y_0)\|_1 \geq \alpha ||y_0||_2.$$
Since $T$ is bijective, we have $T(x_0)=y_0$ for some $x_0 \in E$, so we can do $$\|T^{-1}(T(x_0))\|_1\geq \alpha \|T(x_0)\|_2 \Longrightarrow ||x_0||_1 \geq \alpha \|T(x_0)\|_2$$
is this enought to claim that is absurd that $T^{-1} is not continuous$?

If we suppose that $T^{-1}$ is continuous, can we use a similar argument? I'm having some troubles with this part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\|T(x)\|_2 \geq \alpha \|x\|_1$ for all $x \in E$ iff $\|y\|_2 \geq \alpha \|T^{-1}(y)\|_1$ for all $y \in F$ iff $\frac 1 {\alpha}\|y\|_2 \geq  \|T^{-1}(y)\|_1$ for all $y \in F$  iff $T^{-1}$ is bounded.

The first equivalence follows from the fact that $T$ is surjective: any $y \in F$ is of the form $T(x)$ for some $x \in E$.